# Openfire server crashes randomly

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, hazelcast

Deployment:
3 openfire instances in a cluster using hazelcast clustering plugin 2.1.2. We have two custom plugins doing work in addition to the clustering plugin.

Connections(BOSH and TCP):
No of connections: around 10,000 at peak load time.

Nature of the problem:
We are seeing random crashes. It manifests at random times. A few observations around this time is the number of threads of the openfire process shoots up to 30,000 in a few seconds. A java stack trace tells us that almost all these threads are BLOCKED on some operation. The stack trace is pasted for your  reference here.

Stack trace that was observed is

"TaskEngine-pool-64675" #68993 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f125502e800 nid=0x54e7 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f1312156000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2035)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000004e58dfd00> (a java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession.deliver(HttpSession.java:1004)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession.deliver(HttpSession.java:970)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalSession.process(LocalSession.java:289)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.routeToBareJID(RoutingTableImpl.java:633)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.routeToLocalDomain(RoutingTableImpl.java:303)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.routePacket(RoutingTableImpl.java:239)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SocketPacketWriteHandler.process(SocketPacketWriteHandler.java:68)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketDelivererImpl.deliver(PacketDelivererImpl.java:56)
        at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession$4.run(HttpSession.java:1083)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The above is the jstack output while the thread count has reached a high value like 30,000 and the server is unresponsive. Any pointers? The trace seems to indicate that the data structure cant be accessed.

Comment: What version of openfire ?

Comment: My mistake. openfire version 3.10.2, hazelcast version 3.5.1

Comment: It seems a bug in openfire, but I downloaded the source code and the line numbers are different from the one in your stacktrace. It would be possible to investigate the deadlock only if we know the version of the source code

Comment: Its is the 3.10.2 version, released on 6/22/2015. The HttpSession.java has a deliver function that is called to deliver pending packets in the event of a connection close. This keeps adding the packets to a data structure holding a lock. All thread seem blocked on this monitor.